# Trying to make an App in React which draws a rectangle in the location of a canvas component where I click my cursor

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas, coordinates

I have created an app where I want to draw a rectangle on a canvas when a user clicks on a specific location. However, I'm facing an issue where the rectangle appears in an incorrect location on the canvas. I have checked my code and CSS, but I can't seem to identify the problem.

Here's an overview of my code:

The app is built using React and I have a component called TimeLineApp that renders the canvas container.
The canvas element is implemented in the TimeLineAppCanvas component, where I handle the click event and draw the rectangle using the getContext method.
I have also defined CSS styles for the canvas container (#TimeLineApp) and the canvas element itself.
However, despite my efforts, the rectangle is not appearing in the expected location on the canvas. I suspect that there might be an issue with my CSS rules or how I'm calculating the coordinates.

Can anyone please help me identify the cause of this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[CodeSandbox Link to My Project](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/matthewjparkes/TimeShaper/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknad6000b376k56a3s3sc%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522panelType%2522%253A%2522TABS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknad6000d376klp8or7yf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clihknad6000b376k56a3s3sc%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknad6000b376k56a3s3sc%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clihlwckm005m376khuh11nhp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknad6000a376k9wo502kf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FTimeLineApp%252FTimeLineApp.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihlwckm005m376khuh11nhp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clihknad6000d376klp8or7yf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknad6000d376klp8or7yf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clihknu0z00ct376k0c189cvl%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknraz007s376kpx95682j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clihknu0z00ct376k0c189cvl%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Here is my my Mousecoordinates component

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function MousePosition(global){
const [mouseCoords, setMouseCoords] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
})

const handleCursorMovement = (e) => {
    let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    setMouseCoords({
        x: ((e.clientX)- (rect.left)),
        y: (e.clientY - rect.top) 
    });
    console.log( 'Canvas',  mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y)
    console.log(e.target.getBoundingClientRect())
    console.log( 'Actual',  e.clientX);
};


useEffect(() => {
    if(global){
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleCursorMovement);
    }
    return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleCursorMovement);
         };
    }, [global]);
   
return [mouseCoords, handleCursorMovement];

    }

export default MousePosition;
```

Here is my TimeLineAppCanvas component

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react'
import MousePosition from './MouseCoordinates';

const TimeLineAppCanvas = props => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [coords, handleCoords] = MousePosition(true);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props}
    onClick={(e) => {
      handleCoords((e));
      if (canvasRef.current) {
        const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx?.strokeRect(coords.x, coords.y, 20, 30);
      }
    }}/>
  }

export default TimeLineAppCanvas
```

Here is my CSS

```
#TimeLineApp{
    width:75%;
    height: 50%;
    /* width: 400px;
    height: 500px; */
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

#TimeLineApp canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Here is the container:

```
import './TimeLineApp.css'
import TimeLineAppCanvas from './Files/TimeLineAppCanvas';

function TimeLineApp() {



    return(
    <div>
        <TimeLineAppCanvas id='TimeLineApp' ></TimeLineAppCanvas>
    </div>
    )
}

export default TimeLineApp
```

Comment: Why don't you use some of the free online editors to place your snippet? It would be easier to investigate the problem.

Comment: Good idea - have added to the main post

Comment: Strange, I can't see any `canvas` on that page.

Comment: apologies have updated the link

Comment: I think you don't get the coordinates right. See this sample: https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/javascript-mouse-drawing-on-the-canvas/ to get the mouse coordinates.